# Changes in Excel export format - how can we be notified of changes?

Tags: excel, export, surveymonkey, changelog

I received an xlsx file from a client recently. The headings were changed eg "Respondent ID" is now "respondent_id". Also, three new columns appeared: User ID, Session ID, Medium. I can't find them by googling site:surveymonkey.com and the columns are blank. Please provide some documentation.

It would be helpful if you could email us with notification of such changes in advance. How can I sign up to such notification?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be directed to your client?

Comment: Are you saying that SM did not make these changes, but the client did? (I would not have expected them to know to make those changes but I may be underestimating them). If so, I can  certainly ask them.

Comment: I don't know who made the changes, but I would address the question of how to be notified to whoever you think is responsible. If you want to figure out how to determine if changes have been made yourself, you could, for example, write a routine comparing the expected with the actual format, to trigger a notification to yourself if the format has changed.  If you choose to do that, and have problems, edit your question (or start a new one) showing your code, explaining the problem in your code, and providing an example others can use to reproduce your coding problem.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I asked in the wrong place. SO is for coding questions, my question should have been directed to Surveymonkey API support.